# What is a "sing song soldier"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase "a sing song soldier"?  A teacher was helping a student in crisis and another teacher referred to her as a sing song soldier.  I have not been able to find any reference to its meaning by doing a standard internet search.  Thanks!

Comment: The alliteration could indicate it's disparaging. Do you have any more context than a bald description?

Comment: Disparage means "of little worth". So, are you implying that a "sing song soldier" means that it is someone of little worth?

Comment: I would *guess* it refers to someone who tries really hard to inject their perhaps unwanted help into every situation.

Comment: It could have been imported from another culture. I have never heard it. It does remind be a bit of Dudley Do-Right.

Comment: It’s not a standard idiom. It could mean any number of things; you’ll have to provide more background information (what was the crisis? how was the teacher helping? what is the relationship between the two teachers? what is the entire context in which all this takes place?, etc.) in order for anyone to be able to make an educated guess. It could be positive, or it could be negative.

Comment: Either way, it could be an idiom or a real person. Perhaps more context would help, such as if this was part of a certain genre of book.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/singsong and http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/singsong

Comment: The first teacher was a "singsong soldier" or the (female) student. It's not clear from your description.

Comment: Was this teacher an English native speaker? It is possible that she translated an idiom in her mother tongue in English, or mixed two idioms together as suggested by Joe Blow. Sometimes "soldier" is used as a compliment, to say that the child/person is obedient, and follows instructions/orders.

Comment: Voting to close because it is unclear.

Comment: In your question, does 'she' refer to the teacher or the student?  Did you hear this recently or did you read it? If so, when did the action take place?

Comment: I have heard/read this idiom a few times, but can only guess at the meaning and etymology.

Answer (score 1):

Just FTR the simple answer is **it is not a standard idiom**.

That's all we can help you with here.

The person who said it was making something up on the spot, or it refers to a specific (say) TV show, or it was just a mistake.

(Note that it is extremely commonplace in English that people confuse and mangle idioms.)

Answer (score 1):

A Google Books search does turn up a few matches for "sing song [or singsong] soldier," but they are surely unrelated to whatever usage the person quoted in the OP's question had in mind. Specifically, the phrase seems to be connected to a Chinese export brand of cloth in the early 1900s.

From [*Journal of the Royal Society of Arts*](https://books.google.com/books?id=29jqCZ6nXZIC&q=%22sing+song+soldier%22&dq=%22sing+song+soldier%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xtxzVc6aGc61ogTl7oLwDQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBA), volume 61 (1913) [combined snippets]:

> In India, and still more in China, goods bearing a favourite mark command quite materially better prices than identical goods under a mark less known. In the immense majority of cases the marks are the property not of the manufacturer but of the exporter, and their presence is a potent stimulus to him to keep the quality up to the standard. One or two disappointing deliveries are enough in China to consign a "chop" to the cold shades of neglect for three years. The salient features of these marks and gaudy labels lend their names to the "chops," and in a Shanghai auction list of piece-goods, one reads such names as these: Eagle and Fish, Home Ruler-Favourable Market, War God, Blue Crab, Tiger and Boy, Black Tea Caddy, Painted Three Students, **Sing Song Soldier** and Man, Motor Car, Empty City, Beautiful Rocks, followed by quotations of prices.

From Ralph Odell, [*Cotton Goods in China*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kUlAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA234&dq=%22singsong+soldier%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1eBzVcKrBcvXoASHqqdo&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22singsong%20soldier%22&f=false) (1916):

> Sample 89.—Grey shirting; “**Singsong Soldier** and Man” chop; manufactured in England; 38 inches wide; 72 by 72 construction; 14¾ pounds per piece (2.61 yards per pound). Auction price in March, 1915, 5.70 Shanghai taels ($3.13) per piece of 38½ yards (8.13 cents per yard).

From Harvard University Bureau of Business Research, "[International Comparisons of Prices of Cotton Cloth](https://books.google.com/books?id=Bs4UAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA24&dq=%22sing+song+soldier%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lOJzVcqRKYStogT50YOgBg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22sing%20song%20soldier%22&f=false)" (1920):

> CHINESE AND AMERICAN ... *Shanghai* **Sing Song Soldier** Man 72 X 72 [Construction] 2.61 [Linear yards per pound] 19.0 [Number of yarn]
>
> [Footnote] These fabrics are quoted as "chops" or brands and the construction is not given in the quotations. ...

Google Books searches find no other instances of "sing song (or *singsong*) soldier," suggesting that the phrase is not in widespread idiomatic use in English.

Comment: It may be a literal translation of a Chinese idiom, given that all its occurrences seem to be in China.